# Select multiple XML elements in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, xquery

I am passing the following xml to a SQL Server stored procedure:

```
<root>
    <id>6063</id>
    <id>6064</id>
</root>
```

In my stored procedure I have the following code to select the id:

```
SELECT t.n.value('id[1]', 'int')
FROM @xml.nodes('/root') as t(n)
```

Now this works however it obviously only selects the first id and stops. I am not quite sure how to make this 'loop' and select all the id's in the xml file.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Here is the full stored procedure for reference:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE @xml xml = '<root>
                        <id>6063</id>
                        <id>6064</id>
                    </root>'

SELECT t.n.value('id[1]', 'int') as id
FROM @xml.nodes('/root') as t(n)

END
```

Comment: It looks okay to me. As per **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758091/how-to-loop-and-parse-xml-parameter-in-sql-server-stored-procedure)** SO article, it should work as written. Maybe you need to do a **t.n.value('id[1]', 'int') as 'ID'** as well?

Comment: ok I have tried adding 'as id' however that hasn't helped. I will copy the sp into the question.

Comment: could anyone please tell why above code is not selecting all ids?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This SQL should work for you:

```
DECLARE @xml xml = '<root>
                        <id>6063</id>
                        <id>6064</id>
                    </root>'

SELECT t.n.value('text()[1]', 'int') as id
FROM @xml.nodes('/root/id') as t(n)
```

The result from this query is:

```
id
----
6063
6064
```

Instead of selecting from the `root` element, I selected all `id` elements under `root` and used `text()` to read in the value.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks . i was facing exactly same issue.