# Parsing multiple xml elements from an xmlstring in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-update

My input xml string is

```
<users><id>p1</id><id>p2</id><id>p3</id></users>
```

i want to write an update query to update the column 'Request_Status' in my table if the id matches to the ones in the xml string

I tried this statement:

```
Update login set 
            Request_Status='A'
            where
            EmpId in
            (
                SELECT Pers.value('(id)[1]', 'nchar(10)') as 'ID'
                FROM
                        @xmlUserId.nodes('/users') as EMP(Pers)
            )
```

This only updates for ID p1 and not for the other 2.

I referred to this,

[How to loop and parse xml parameter in sql server stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758091/how-to-loop-and-parse-xml-parameter-in-sql-server-stored-procedure)

(P.S my first question here, so please excuse mistakes, unconventional elements in the post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the XML selection query to be as follow :

```
SELECT Pers.value('self::*', 'nchar(10)') as 'ID'
FROM
        @xmlUserId.nodes('/users/id') as EMP(Pers)
```

Above query should return *all* `<id>` element within `<users>` element

**[[SQL fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/40323)]**

Comment: @ShounakGujarathi see the demo, it works given input XML string you posted. Create a new fiddle to demonstrate how this doesn't work so we can check further

Comment: Yes, it seems to be working in the fiddle. I can't add an Update Statement there though..
(
 Update login set 
   Request_Status='A'
   where EmpId in ( 
        SELECT Pers.value('self::*', 'nchar(20)')
        FROM
        @xmlUserId.nodes('/users/id') as EMP(Pers)
);

Comment: Dude nvm, i restarted sql server and it worked. Thanks a lot.