# Passing XML multi level data as parameter and using in stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have XML format data which I will pass from a .net application.

In the SQL Server stored procedure, this data is passed in as a XML parameter. I want to read and save the data in the required tables, say `TblOrder` and `TblItem`.

In XML, there will be multiple orders. Each order contains one or several items accordingly.

Structure on which operation need to be implemented:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Orders>
  <Order>
    <B2>B2**ABIJ**0000884443**PP</B2>
    <CreateBy null="true" />
    <CreateDate>/Date(1485150414358)/</CreateDate>
    <CurrencyId>1</CurrencyId>
    <CustomerId>13</CustomerId>
    <DeliveryAddress>LIBERTY PRESS LLC</DeliveryAddress>
    <DeliveryCity>SPRINGVILLE UT 84663</DeliveryCity>
    <DeliveryCityId>0</DeliveryCityId>
    <DeliveryDate>/Date(1478750400000)/</DeliveryDate>
    <DeliveryId>14</DeliveryId>
    <DeliveryState>UT</DeliveryState>
    <DeliveryStateId>16</DeliveryStateId>
    <DeliveryType>Delivery</DeliveryType>
    <EquipmentId>4</EquipmentId>
    <Items>
      <Item>
        <CSA>false</CSA>
        <CTPAT>false</CTPAT>
        <CommodityItem>General Freight</CommodityItem>
        <CommodityItemId>0</CommodityItemId>
        <CustCommodityItem null="true" />
        <FAST>false</FAST>
        <Hazmat>false</Hazmat>
        <Height null="true" />
        <IsActive>false</IsActive>
        <ItemId>0</ItemId>
        <ItemName>Item A</ItemName>
        <Length null="true" />
        <Make null="true" />
        <Mass null="true" />
        <MassUnit null="true" />
        <Model null="true" />
        <OrderId>0</OrderId>
        <PIP>false</PIP>
        <PilotCar>false</PilotCar>
        <ReeferTemp null="true" />
        <Tarp>false</Tarp>
        <TrailerType null="true" />
        <TruckType null="true" />
        <VIN null="true" />
        <Width null="true" />
        <Year null="true" />
      </Item>
    </Items>
    <L11>L11*SYL884443*BM</L11>
    <LastUpdate>/Date(1485150414358)/</LastUpdate>
  </Order>
  <Order>
    ...
    <Items>
      <Item>
        ...
      </Item>
    </Order>
</Orders>
```

Steps I want to achieve are:

- Read XML parameter from the stored procedure, which is passed from the .net application.
- Loop through the XML and save data in the `TblOrder` and `TblItem` tables

Going through the article follows :

- [Pass-XML-parameter-to-Stored-Procedure](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Pass-XML-parameter-to-Stored-Procedure-in-C-and-VBNet.aspx)
- [How to loop and parse xml parameter in sql server stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758091/how-to-loop-and-parse-xml-parameter-in-sql-server-stored-procedure)

I got the Idea to access very first level (in my case Order of Orders).
Moving forward having issue accessing the second level which will be again a collection (in my case Item of Items of Order).

Thanks in advance for your support

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is

Comment: Why do you want to parse xml in SQL when you can do it in c#?

Comment: I have schenerio where I need to pass XML data as parameter from .Net application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two approaches:

- You can pass the XML *as-is* into a Stored Procedure and do all the hard work in T-SQL
- You can shredd the XML within C#, fill appropriate data objects and use classical data storage.

From your question I take, that you'd prefer to pass this into a stored procedure as XML parameter. There are some things to know:

- C# uses *16-bit-unicode* internally and so does SQL Server's XML. But you will not be able to cast this unicode string to XML as long as there is `encoding="UTF-8"` included... You might pass this as `VARCHAR(MAX)` (not `NVARCHAR(MAX)`!), but this could lead you in troubles if there are sepcial characters involved. Best was, to cut the first line (the `<?xml ...?>` declaration) away completely.
- Your XML is not created correctly. Is this under you control? If you include `null="true"` (there's no need for normally!), you should do this with the `xsi`-namespace. And date/time values *within* XML should be ISO8601. Your values (like `/Date(1485150414358)/`) are no format SQL Server will be able to cast directly...

Nevertheless I see multi `<Order>`-elements and multi `<Item>`-elements. You could read them as follows:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<Orders>
  <Order>
    <B2>B2**ABIJ**0000884443**PP</B2>
    <CreateBy null="true" />
    <CreateDate>/Date(1485150414358)/</CreateDate>
    <CurrencyId>1</CurrencyId>
    <CustomerId>13</CustomerId>
    <DeliveryAddress>LIBERTY PRESS LLC</DeliveryAddress>
    <DeliveryCity>SPRINGVILLE UT 84663</DeliveryCity>
    <DeliveryCityId>0</DeliveryCityId>
    <DeliveryDate>/Date(1478750400000)/</DeliveryDate>
    <DeliveryId>14</DeliveryId>
    <DeliveryState>UT</DeliveryState>
    <DeliveryStateId>16</DeliveryStateId>
    <DeliveryType>Delivery</DeliveryType>
    <EquipmentId>4</EquipmentId>
    <Items>
      <Item>
        <CSA>false</CSA>
        <CTPAT>false</CTPAT>
        <CommodityItem>General Freight</CommodityItem>
        <CommodityItemId>0</CommodityItemId>
        <CustCommodityItem null="true" />
        <FAST>false</FAST>
        <Hazmat>false</Hazmat>
        <Height null="true" />
        <IsActive>false</IsActive>
        <ItemId>0</ItemId>
        <ItemName>Item A</ItemName>
        <Length null="true" />
        <Make null="true" />
        <Mass null="true" />
        <MassUnit null="true" />
        <Model null="true" />
        <OrderId>0</OrderId>
        <PIP>false</PIP>
        <PilotCar>false</PilotCar>
        <ReeferTemp null="true" />
        <Tarp>false</Tarp>
        <TrailerType null="true" />
        <TruckType null="true" />
        <VIN null="true" />
        <Width null="true" />
        <Year null="true" />
      </Item>
    </Items>
    <L11>L11*SYL884443*BM</L11>
    <LastUpdate>/Date(1485150414358)/</LastUpdate>
  </Order>
</Orders>';
```

--the query

```
SELECT --elements of Order
       o.value(N'(B2)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS B2

      --very strange date-format...
      ,o.value(N'(CreateDate)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS CreateDate
      --typed INT
      ,o.value(N'(CurrencyId)[1]',N'int') AS CurrencyId

      --more like this

      --elements of Item
      ,i.value(N'(CSA)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS CSA

      --There's no need for *null="true"*
      --Query the "/text()" and the empty element will be NULL
      ,CASE WHEN i.value(N'(CustCommodityItem/@null)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')=N'true' THEN NULL ELSE i.value(N'(CustCommodityItem)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') END AS CustCommodityItem_complicated
      ,i.value(N'(CustCommodityItem)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS CustCommodityItem_empty
      ,i.value(N'(CustCommodityItem/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS CustCommodityItem_null


FROM @xml.nodes(N'/Orders/Order') AS A(o)
OUTER APPLY o.nodes(N'Items/Item') AS B(i)
```

Comment: Thanks @Shnugo ,It works for me .Can you please share some links which can explore XML in SQL server more .

Comment: @UJS Just use a search engine and search for "SQL Server XML" and you will find tons of tutorials. One good site - at least people say so - should be www.stackoverflow.com and if you visit a user profile (I think it's called *Shnugo*) you'll find many answered questions *grin*